# Recoding a variable to be a factor w/ level names in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, r-factor

Using my data-set **bikeshare** I want to recode the variable **season** to be a factor with meaningful level names (i.e "winter", "spring", "summer", "fall"), with spring as the baseline level.

Here is my attempt:

```
bikeshare <- bikeshare %>%
mutate(season = factor(c(1 = "winter", 
                      2 = "spring", 
                      3 = "summer", 
                      4 = "fall")))
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied 
to an object of class "factor"
```

I'd appreciate any help, I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to convert number (`1:4`) to factor ("winter", "spring", "summer", "fall"). The key is to use the `factor` function and set the `levels` and `labels` accordingly.

```
# Create example data frame
bikeshare <- data.frame(season = 1:4)

bikeshare
#   season
# 1      1
# 2      2
# 3      3
# 4      4

library(dplyr)

bikeshare2 <- bikeshare %>%
  mutate(season = factor(as.character(season), 
                         levels = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                         labels = c("winter", "spring", "summer", "fall")))
bikeshare2
#   season
# 1 winter
# 2 spring
# 3 summer
# 4   fall
```

Answer (score 0):

To create your factor, you need to provide your data and your season labels to the `factor()` function.

However, since you want Spring to be the baseline level, I believe you will have to specify the levels and labels in a specific order - forcing spring to be first:

```r
bikeshare <- data.frame(season = 1:4)

bikeshare$seasonfactor <- factor(x = bikeshare$season,
                                 levels = c(2,3,4,1), 
                                 labels = c("spring", "summer", "fall", "winter"))

str(bikeshare$seasonfactor)
#>  Factor w/ 4 levels "spring","summer",..: 4 1 2 3

bikeshare
#>   season seasonfactor
#> 1      1       winter
#> 2      2       spring
#> 3      3       summer
#> 4      4         fall
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

This is a tiny bit confusing, because in `seasonfactor`, Spring is represented by a 1, but in the original `season` it is represented by a 2.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to label the integer levels, with the help of the `labelled` package. So they remain integers but with the labels as metadata. If at any point you want to convert the labelled integers to factors, you can achieve that with the `to_factor` function.

```r
library("tidyverse")
library("labelled")

labels <- c(
  "winter" = 1,
  "spring" = 2,
  "summer" = 3,
  "fall" = 4)

bikeshare <-
  tibble(season = 1:4) %>%
  mutate(season = labelled(season, labels)) %>%
  mutate(seasonF = to_factor(season))
bikeshare
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>       season seasonF
#>    <int+lbl> <fct>  
#> 1 1 [winter] winter 
#> 2 2 [spring] spring 
#> 3 3 [summer] summer 
#> 4 4 [fall]   fall
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>